# using BC dates in Drupal date field

Tags: drupal, date, drupal-6

I am trying to input BC dates in Drupal 6.15 using the Date module. If I enter "old" dates (less than 1000 AD) I get an error. How can I go about this? I cannot revert to text because I need to order things by their date. I need to be able to input really ancient dates like 300 BC. The date is the most important data point in this particular project.

- Drupal 6.15
- MySQL database 4.1.25
- PHP 5.2.6
- Web server Apache/2.0.54
- CCK 6.x-2.6
- Date Module  6.x-2.4: Text Field with Date pop-up calendar
- Input format 2009/12/22 with years back/forward -2600:+2

Thanks

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Which CCK widget type are you using? If you are using the widget "Textfield with custom input format", which one is the input format?

Comment: @riggs: lol

Edited with server and module details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging in the MySQL docs. I don't believe that it can support dates earlier than 1000AD (see [here](http://help.scibit.com/Mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html)).

Postgres SQL has better support for dates going from [4713 BC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-datetime.html), is switching to that an option for you?

Another option would be to do something clunky like using a number field and customizing the output to get it to look like a date. That way you can still order the field and have a good range. Have a look [here](http://drupal.org/node/106716) to see how to create your own CCK field, it is quite involved.

Comment: thanks... what I ended up doing was separating year, month and day in three different int fields... this way I keep "the best of both worlds"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://drupal.org/project/partial_date for Drupal 7 - handles from 999999999999BC to 999999999999AD